# DelphiScript, Altium Designer V23, EXPECTING ;

Tags: altium-designer, delphiscript

I was working with DelphiScript, and I have a problem, I have the message

> expecting ;

I try to solve it, but it is still the same.

The code is this:

```
procedure CrearPistaDeCobre;
var
    PCBBoard: IPCB_Board;
    Track: IPCB_Track;
    StartPoint, EndPoint: TCoordPoint;
begin
// Obtener la placa activa
    PCBBoard := PCBServer.GetCurrentPCBBoard;
    if PCBBoard = nil then
    begin
        ShowMessage('No hay una placa activa.');
        Exit;
    end;

    // Crear un objeto de pista
    Track := PCBBoard.AddPCBObject(eTrackObject, eNoDimension) as IPCB_Track;

    // Verificar que el objeto creado sea de tipo IPCB_Track
    if Track <> nil then
    begin
        // Establecer los puntos de inicio y fin de la pista
        StartPoint := PCBServer.PCBPointFactory.CreatePoint(0, 0);
        EndPoint := PCBServer.PCBPointFactory.CreatePoint(MilsToCoord(10000), MilsToCoord(0)); // Convertir mils a coordenadas

        // Establecer las propiedades de la pista
        Track.SetState_Object(eRouting);
        Track.SetWidthInCoord(MilsToCoord(2000)); // Ancho de la pista en mils
        Track.SetLayer(LayerStackup.LayerByIndex(3)); // Layer 4 en Altium es índice 3
        Track.SetStartPoint(StartPoint);
        Track.SetEndPoint(EndPoint);

        // Actualizar la placa
        PCBBoard.GraphicallyInvalidate;

        ShowMessage('Pista de cobre creada exitosamente.');
    end;
    else
    begin
        ShowMessage('Error al crear la pista de cobre o el objeto no es de tipo IPCB_Track.');
    end;
end;

// Llamar a la función principal
CrearPistaDeCobre;
```

The error its from this line I think:

```
Track := PCBBoard.AddPCBObject(eTrackObject, eNoDimension) as IPCB_Track;
```

I tried to check all the `;` at the end but nothing changed.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Altium is not very clear on the error messages.

My guess is that the way you are assigning values to Track is not supported.

Maybe you have to add the track to the PCBBoard and then after assign it to Track.

Now 100% but just giving ideas to try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).